# False value converted to True during insert-select on Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

We have an use case where Spark writes to a temporary hive Table and then an insert-select runs to write to the target table. For boolean type columns False values in the temporary tables are inserted as True in the target table. There is nothing fancy with the insert-select:

> insert overwrite table {schema}.table  partition(year,month,day)
> select * from
> {tmp schema}.tmp_{table}

Both are partitioned by the same columns(year,month,day) and spark inserts(using overwrite) to: {tmp schema}.tmp_{table}

Why could the values change?

Comment: Could you try to design a minimal instance of your problem, and try to give us enough information so that we can reproduce it?

Comment: Pls check column sequence carefully. Put source and target definitions in a xl and compare.

Comment: are  source table columns boolean or string?

Comment: They are exactly the same in both source and target, they are boolean and only happens for boolean columns